# can't run rails server (activesupport error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

in my application, in the last few days, i'm unable to run the `rails server/rails s` or even `bundle exec rails server` command any more.
it was running like a charm before.

i tried to revert the changes using git, but no luck, i tried all the possible proprieties i could think of.
i use rubymine, but same problem when using the Terminal .

when i run:

```
ma@SL510:~/ts$ rails server
```

i get the following error stack trace :

```
from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_request.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:103:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/ma/ts/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

i don't know how could i fix this, to get the rails server command to run again !
any help would be appreciate it !

ps: please tell me if i need to provide more info. Thanks.

Comment: Did you upgrade Ruby?

Comment: yes! it was on of the many things i did ! do you think this might be the reason ?

i will try to reuse the old version and see. if that will fix it!

Comment: I read on another thread that upgrading might cause the issue. If you are using RVM, it should be simple to revert.

Comment: Actually reverting to older version of ruby did not work, because in so many places of the code, the new ":" notation is used instead of the ": =>"

Comment: Did you try to create a brand new gemset (and use it), then `bundle install` gems ? The stacktrace seems to indicate you're using the global gemset, which is a really bad idea. Another suggestion : IMO you should not use Unicorn with your development env.

Comment: @Jef
thank you so much, creating a new gemset, and bundle install AND using gem install unicorn, fixed the problem ! 
can you please try to explain to me why using the global gemset is bad? it was the default setting in RubyMine, i did not change it.

and why it's bad to use Unicorn in dev env?

Comment: @Mawaheb Per-project gemsets allow you to manage your gems on a per-project basis, checkout https://rvm.io/rvm/best-practices/ (best practice #3).

Comment: Thanks alot @Jef , and if you want, you can write your comment that fixed my prblem as an answer, and i will choose it as right one and delete the one i posted myself :) thanks alot again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to create a brand new gemset (and use it), then `bundle install` so that Bundler install gems listed in your Gemfile. The stacktrace seems to indicate you're using the global gemset, which is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jef
creating a new gemset and using it
and after this:

```
gem install unicorn
```

fixed the problem with that command :)